# how to summarize sql result, week and month wise in single query

Tags: sql, asp.net, gridview

I want to summarize sql query result week wise and month wise at the same time in a grid view. Is this even possible or I am just dreaming?

`Requirement:`

1. Show last one month data and next two month's data week wise in the grid.

   `Example-`

   - If the current month is September then I want to show data from 1st August to 31st October categorized in weeks.
2. Show the data after the next month of current month in month wise view in the same grid.

   `Example-`

   - data for month November and December will be shown categorized in month not in weeks.

grid or result should look something like below -

[image]

Please suggest something to achieve this

Comment: have 2 different queries

Answer (score 1):

I think you must work with     group by  or  group by ... cube

```
SELECT x , y from <tabel> GROUP BY  date_feld( to_char( 'MM' ))
```

but i don't now your DBMS so i can't give you a exact example for the date handling.

Comment: my table will have a date column I want to pick rows for 1 year. and summarize the result as described in my post.

Comment: select sum(x) from <table> group by date_feld( to_char( 'yy' ))

Answer (score 1):

If you want a maintainable solution, use two independent queries, one for weekly aggregation other for monthly. Depending on the input run corresponding query.

Comment: I will always pick one year data I just want to summarize it as described above in the post so that I can show it in grid.

Comment: That is still 2 different queries possibly joined by common attributed.